# Bad review for link answer

Tags: discussion, review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/15800351

The question asked for a way to test a website with Samsung mobile device browser.

The answer was a link to a Samsung website when we can test a website using lot of its devices.

Obviously if we take the rules/guidelines to the dot the answer it's bad. But in this case the answer cannot contain an excerpt of code extracted from the linked website, or the idea of the contents of the website. It's a service which does what the question is looking for.

I see lots of posts like this on meta, because it seems this kind of question for test if the reviewer it's doing a good job are not being checked by an human.

Comment: Well in this case the question itself is just a product recommendation question, so it should just be closed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the "answer" really did answer the question, in a way, but the question was bad, as [pointed out in the comments above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347745/bad-review-for-link-answer#comment464643_347745). When a question asks for recommendations for off-site resources, that question should be closed. In other words, the best thing to do is take a step away from the review queue for a second and vote (or flag) for closure (depending on your privileges).

The system identifies audits automatically based on reviews and other actions that got unanimous agreement. We (moderators or the community as a whole) can't possibly review enough posts to make sure that we have enough audits in the system, but only good audits are being selected. Inevitably, some bad ones get through. As long as you're paying attention and doing good reviews most of the time, this isn't going to be a problem for you.

All that said, the answer was still bad, even though that's the fault of the question. As you said, the answer itself can't possibly contain a complete answer to the question; it's no more than a pointer to another site. **The result here is that the question was bad and should be closed, *and* the answer was very low quality (VLQ) by this site's standards and should be deleted entirely or converted by a moderator into a comment.** You should handle a situation like this by voting to close the question (or raising a flag, depending on your privileges), not by taking no action on a bad answer to a bad question.

Comment: Ok I understand. I checked the question, but I was reviewing the answer, so I payed attention to if it resolved that question. Thankfor the explanation, I will take more attention next time.